# F(a,b) function, find a,b for the max value of f

Tags: numerical-methods

My numerical processing days are long ago and I'm trying to remember the name of the method to find the maximum of a 2D function. What I want is the values a,b that will maximize f(a,b)

Said function has two parameters within a certain range and takes a LONG time to compute, so the method should minimize the number of calls.

I remember in 1D, there's Newton's method. Anything relevant here beside a brutal double loop ? Bonus if it's a C implementation.

Comment: You can use Newton method for 2D too. There are also semi-Newton methods like L-BFGS that work pretty good

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently testing out a C implementation of that.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, L-BFGS seem to require a gradient function. In my case that is non-computable. Are there methods that don't require it, or that can evaluate it on the fly ?

Comment: Yes it needs the gradient function, from wikipedia: [The algorithm's target problem is to minimize f(x) over unconstrained values of the real-vector x  where f is a differentiable scalar function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS). AFAIK all of these methods are gradient based. Methods like Genetic algorithm do not require gradients.